# Unusual behoiur in tmux, Tab clears the pane when it's not set to

Tags: terminal, tmux, neovim

For some unknown reason in Tmux the 'Tab' key clears the pane I'm in, which is annoying when I use 'Tab' to indent in Neovim and 'Shift Tab' to unindent.

Is there a way to fix this (stop 'Tab' clearing my panes and work as intended)

I've tested this in the default Mac terminal and iterm2, and it happens in both.

Outside of Tmux the 'Tab' key works fine in both terminals, indenting 4 or so spaces.

Also, I have C-i mapped to clear a pane usually.

Here is my .tmux.conf for reference:

```
set -g default-terminal 'screen-256color'

set -g prefix C-a
unbind C-b
bind-key C-a send-prefix


unbind %
bind | split-window -h

unbind '"'
bind - split-window -v

unbind r
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf

bind -r j resize-pane -D 5
bind -r k resize-pane -U 5
bind -r l resize-pane -R 5
bind -r h resize pane -L 5

bind -r m resize-pane -Z

set -g mouse on

set-window-option -g mode-keys vi

bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'v' send -X begin-selection 
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'y' send -X copy-selection

unbind -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane

bind C-i send-keys -R \; send-keys C-l \; clear-history

set -sg escape-time 10

set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'

set -g @plugin 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'
set -g @plugin 'jimeh/tmux-themepack'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum'

set-g @thempack 'powerline/default/cyan'

set -g resurrect-capture-pane-contents 'on'
set -g @continuum-restore 'on'

run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
```

Comment: Ctrl+a to Ctrl+z type control characters 1 through 26. Some of them may be intercepted by the terminal driver (e.g. Ctrl+c usually makes it send SIGINT to the foreground process group), others are passed verbatim. As `i` is the 9th letter, Ctrl+i sends the character 9 which happens to be Tab. For your terminal Ctrl+i *is* Tab. This is how terminals and terminal emulators work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ctrl-i and Tab have the same ASCII code `0x09`.

I thought just commenting on the C-i binding would work, but I had to unbind C-i in the .tmux.conf.

```
# bind -n C-i send-keys -R \; send-keys C-l \; clear-history
  unbind -n C-i
```

did the trick