# Tab key working as prefix key in tmux

Tags: terminal, tmux

I've remapped my prefix key to Control-I(C-i). It works, but my Tab key now also works as a prefix key, I can't use it for things like autocomplete anymore. I don't know what is causing this, this is my config

```sh
# setup my main session
if-shell "tmux has-session -t main" "" {
  new-session -s main mocp
  new-window nnn
  new-window

  select-window -t :1
}

set-option -s prefix "C-i"
bind-key "C-i" send-prefix
set-option -s display-time 2000
set-option -s status-left ""
set-option -s status-right "|#S|"
set-option -s status-justify right
set-option -s status-style "bg=cyan,fg=black"

bind-key R "source-file "~/.tmux.conf" ; display-message "Reloaded...""
bind-key K kill-session
bind-key "'" last-window
bind-key "j" select-pane -L
bind-key ";" select-pane -R
bind-key "l" select-pane -U
bind-key "k" select-pane -D
bind-key "M-j" resize-pane -L
bind-key "M-;" resize-pane -R
bind-key "M-l" resize-pane -U
bind-key "M-k" resize-pane -D
```

I have tried to unbind it with `unbind-key Tab` but it did not help. How can I fix this?

Comment: [Ctrl+i *is* Tab](https://superuser.com/q/1780289/432690#comment2779170_1780289).

Comment: Thanks, will remap it then.